# x86 interrupt handler gets blocked when using infinite loop

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn x86 assembly and c language. And now I've finished a simple timer and keyboard interrupts. The firs one can print a line every several ticks and the second can print what you've pressed on keyboard.The code is just like:

**Timer.c:**

```
print();
return;
```

**keyboard.c:**

```
print();
return;
```

**main.c:**

```
while(1);
```

these two handlers are in the IDT.  So when an interrupt occurs, the IF flag is cleared. The CPU will ignore other interrupts. 
After initialized  all the configurations in my main function, I finished it with a infinite loop, which is like : `while(1)`.
Ok, this is good, I can see on the screen that those two handlers work.
However, when I want to make it a nested interrupt, I did the following thing:

**Timer.c:**

```
sti();      //set IF to 1 to enable interrupt 
print();
while(1); // wait here to test if the keyboard interrupt can  occur
return;
```

**keyboard.c:**

```
print();
return;
```

**main.c:**

```
while(1);
```

what happened next really consused me: using Bochs, I can see that my program just do the while loop in timer.c. At this moment, I checked the flags, it showed that IF flag had been set, but when I try to type something to test the other interrut, it failed. It just seemed that all the interrupts were blocked or ignored.

The question is, what's the difference between those two loops, one is just in an interrupt handler, also, I dont konw how to solve this problem. I double checked my code in my vmware and virtualbox, but the result was same.

I know this problem must have happened before I met it, however, I can't find anything related to this problem.

Comment: Show a normal MCVE. These chunks cut out of nowhere do not show anything.

Comment: IRQ0 has precedence over IRQ1 using the default PIC1 configuration. Google for EOI if this doesn't ring any bells. Otherwise, it can be the type of interrupt descriptor used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enabling interrupts inside interrupt handler you don't enable only "others" interrupts, but all interrupts. Including the timer interrupt.
(this is too general, payne points out in comment, on x86 there may be different sources of IRQ signals, and particular PIC/APIC chips can be configured to prioritize one over other ... doesn't change anything about the *principle* of re-entrant IRQ handling, but you can fine-tune which IRQs have priority, which may mean you don't need re-entry lock at all in the end, if your configuration prevents it)

Your code doesn't look like re-entrant-aware handler, so if that is how your handler code is done, then your timer keeps firing up new timer interrupts as configured, and because you have `sti` there, they keep re-entering the handler code, filling up slowly stack space until it will overflow (or wrap around, I'm not sure if you are in real or protected mode, and how your stack is set up). Only the last one is of course running, rest is dormant (forever, if the last one doesn't return).

A long-duration interrupt handlers are usually sign of bad code architecture (aim for shortest + fastest possible interrupt handlers, often just filling up some queue with data, which is processed in async way outside of interrupt handler). But if you really need one, and you can't leave other interrupts disabled, you must write the handler as re-entrant one.

```
Re-entrant timer interrupt handler
{
    if (locked) return;   // already handling previous IRQ
        // which means the new IRQ is **IGNORED**! (price for slow handler)
    locked = true;        // lock to prevent further re-entry
    sti();                //set IF to 1 to enable interrupts

    // do the slow stuff here (but not infinite loop of course!)

    // "print();" is not an excellent idea either, for interrupt handler
    // while(1); // this would never ever end at all, so NO.

    // slow stuff finished, ready for next request

    locked = false;       // allow next timer IRQ to process the slow stuff again
    return;
}
```

---

addendum: one more remark, probably "obvious" one, but just to make sure it's clear. Single CPU core can run at the same moment only single "thread" of instructions, i.e. it is either executing your infinite loop inside `main`, or it is executing one of the interrupt handlers. When new IRQ signal comes to CPU and interrupts are enabled, the current CPU state is stored in stack (whether it was in main, or timer or keyboard, doesn't matter), and CPU will switch to the desired interrupt handler. So if you emit IRQs faster than your handlers do finish and return to previous code, you will slowly choke the stack memory with the stored CPU states, and it will never return to the original thread at bottom (the infinite loop inside `main`).

Comment: The sti instruction does not necessarily enable "all interrupts", because prioritization may be happening in the PIC/APIC controller before the interrupt is even presented to the CPU.  See:  "PIC end of interrupt" command (EOI) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_interrupt

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try that when I'm free. First of all, I'm in protected mode and I think I've set the right GDT  and IDT. Could it be this, I used the step debug mode in Bochs, and I set break points on each handler before boot, but when using my so called nested interrupts, I just can't see the any break points work. And when I use print-stack, I can see the stack didn't  grow,  it remained unchanged. Could it be that the CPU is so faster that I cannot see when  the stack is overflow?

Comment: @payne thanks for the comment and good answer, indeed this is important bit of information for OP, as he has sort of two problems in one, the particular detail of x86 timer interrupt handling, requiring the EOI code in handler, and the general one with understanding re-entrancy of interrupts and consequences of slow handlers.

Comment: @kevin in protected mode the user app stack and interrupt handling stack is often different. I never studied details, how to set it up and where to check this configuration, but that's how it looks from user land, my app code stack is never modified by ongoing kernel land interrupts, they have their own stack. As I not OS dev, can't disclose more details. Why your breakpoints don't work on handlers... well, breakpoint is interrupt too, so maybe you have to put them after enabling of interrupts, to make them work. Never debugged **live** x86 interrupt code, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @kevin I always first debugged the code separately in debugger, before setting it up as live interrupt handler, and breakpointing inside handler sounds like you need re-entrancy, and basically opening can of worms and recursive complications. Unless you are absolutely needing this, I would suggest to avoid it, rather debug the handler code in non-live fashion, calling it from main, simulating IRQ conditions, skipping over technical details like cli/sti/eoi, adding those when you know the core of handler works and installing it for live.

Comment: @Ped7g yes, I think you are right. I'm a beginner and there are a lot things need to learn and probably it it "how to learn". But sometimes I truly don't know where to find the right information I need.

Comment: Np, interrupts are quite tricky, it's not uncommon some bugs creep into even official OS versions. Debugging the common core cases is not that difficult, you can usually simulate those conditions easily, what is truly tricky about handlers is to think about all the possible corner cases (like when they modify some queue, which is being processed in main thread, you need correct access locks and atomicity, so both main thread and interrupt operate on correct data, and not some partially modified garbage and they don't end in some dead-lock waiting for each other, etc) and simulate/test those.

Answer (score 2):

Timer interrupts (IRQ0) have priority over keyboard interrupts (IRQ1).

So even though you're enabling interrupts generally (with an sti instruction) in your timer interrupt handler, the primary interrupt controller (PIC) is only going to enable higher priority interrupts until your timer/IRQ0 service routine is complete.

For some additional explanation, see:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.asm.x86/7coo0px-BU4

> Right, that is what happens.  The interrupt controller (the primary
>   one, in this case) which signalled the timer interrupt to the CPU will
>   not allow any equal or lower priority interrupts through until the CPU
>   has told it that the timer interrupt has finished, through the EOI
>   instruction (`outportb(0x20, 0x20)` for the primary interrupt
>   controller).

You *could* technically issue an EOI instruction to the PIC to tell it that handling of IRQ0 is done, but you will potentially set yourself up for some very messy scenarios and race conditions.

It would be much cleaner to let the interrupt handlers just handle their specific interrupts and save associated state.  Then, have your main program watch for the sequence you need (e.g. timer, then keyboard)